# Infer type for interface field based on other field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am defining a generic function that takes an interface as its parameter.
This interface has several fields which of one is a key of the generic parameter.
Another field also takes a key of this generic parameter but I would like to force both to be equal without the need for the user to explicitely specify them.

Here is a concrete and minimal example:

```
// Generic interface representing the parameter of the generic function
interface Inte<DataType extends object, K extends keyof DataType = keyof DataType> {
    key: K;
    fn: (val: DataType[K]) => void;
}

// Define the generic function
function test<DataType extends object>(arg: Inte<DataType>);

// Testing interface
interface Base {
    first: string;
    second: number;
}

// Testing function call
test<Base>({
    key: "first",
    fn: (val: number) => {}, // Error on 'fn', here
});
```

The above code reports an error at the line of definition of `fn` stating that the parameter type (`number`) is not assignable to `string` because it does infer the second parameter of my generic interface, `K`, as being `string | number` even though the `key` should help it find the proper type.

The whole error is (No idea why it puts a random `ReactText` right there. Maybe because I tried this in a `.tsx` file?):

```
Type '(val: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(val: ReactText) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'val' and 'val' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReactText' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

I would life to get an error saying that the parameter MUST be `string` instead of `number`. (And no error at all if I change to do `val: string`.

Is there any solution for this problem? I know I could do `"strictFunctionTypes": false` but that would weaken my type checking right there.

I'm pretty sure there is something I can do to address this issue reliably!

By the way, in case it can be relevant in any way, the real code takes place in a context of React usage meaning I can't change the arguments of the generic function because it's a component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your definition of `Inte`. You give `K` a default value of `keyof DataType`, and don't specify a fixed value in `function test<DataType extends object>(arg: Inte<DataType>)`, which means that it'll /always/ default to `keyof DataType`, even if you call that function with a fixed `key` in mind. One way to fix this is make `test` require a type for `K`:

```
declare function test<DataType extends object, K extends keyof DataType>(arg: Inte<DataType, K>);

// Testing function call
test<Base, "first">({
    key: "first",
    fn: (val: number) => { },
    /*
    ERR on fn:
    Type '(val: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(val: string) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'val' and 'val' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
    */
});
```

Now it'll work fine if you write `(val: string)`. Obviously this is unergonomic, as you need to write out "first" twice. It's hard to avoid this though, as `DataType` is already sort of a floating type parameter, e.g. it's more of a constraint instead of something that can be derived from the inputs. And unfortunately in TS, once you specify one generic parameter, you have to specify *all* of them.

Edit: one common workaround for partial-parameter inference is to use curried functions:

```
function test<DataType extends object>() {
    return function innerTest<K extends keyof DataType>(arg: Inte<DataType, K>) {
        throw new Error("Not yet implemented");
    }
};

test<Base>()({
    key: "first",
    fn: (val: number) => { },
    // still an err, but changing to `val: string` makes it work
});
```

Now `test<DataType>()` essentially creates a tester function with constraint `DataType`. The returned function is what does the inference for `K`.

Comment: I was wondering if I could find a solution by not having to explicitely specify `"string"`. I am a bit sad that I'll have to disable strict function checking to solve this error.

Comment: @Telokis I've added a potential workaround if you wish to avoid that.

Comment: That could be a nice solution but I can't alter the function since it's a React functional component, sadly :(
Thanks for the suggestion, though. I'll be able to use it elsewhere